# What happened to the convenient Twitter icon on question pages?

Tags: support, design, site-promotion

I swear there used to be a Twitter button on question pages, but I thoroughly ignored it since I didn't have a Twitter account.

Now that I have a Twitter account and want to start sharing questions, I can't find the button any more.

Was I crazy/just imagining things before, or is it gone now?  Or am I just ***blind***?

Comment: I still see it. [Example.](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/21227/minecraft-getting-rid-of-large-tree-tops)

Comment: @failbadp.  I don't see it on that page either.  I may need the assistance of freehand circles.

Comment: Thar thou go: http://i.imgur.com/fgptO.png

Comment: Just in case: http://i.imgur.com/jd1id.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm blind, as pointed out by @failbadp in the comments.

For reference:

[image]